# Is duplicating react state the right design approach?

Tags: reactjs

I have an app setup such that index.js contains the main state of my app and is passed down to child components. It uses a single reducer as well. index2.js defines the same state as index.js and uses same reducer logic. I could have just lifted the reducer and state to app.js and share between index.js and index2.js, but, the argument against this is to avoid sharing other code that index2.js doesn't need since I forsee index2.js and its child components to be changing a lot more. Are there any drawbacks of doing this besides violating DRY principle? Any suggestions or thoughts?

Component hierarchy (sample):

```
app.js
+--index.js
   +--childComponentA.js
   +--childComponentB.js
+--index2.js
   +--childComponentA.js
   +--childComponentB.js
```

Comment: Just divide the state into 2 parts managed by 2 diff reducers, 1 reducer to managed the shared part and other to handle the specific one. Duplicacy of the code is never encouraged.

Comment: assuming you have different routes for different index files,basically they are containers ,what @VishalGulati said is true,create different reducers for different index files